# How to handle batch script waiting for input from another batch script

Tags: batch-file, user-input

i need to run some batch scripts from my own batch script. Those scripts are paused couple time during execution and waiting for any key.
How can i determine that inner batch script waiting for input and simulate pressing "enter" from my script ?
Hopefully i succeed to explain my self
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `choice.exe` with a default timeout in the inner batch file.

Choice is in many versions of Windows (early and recent) but not all.  XP doesn't have it for example, but free choice clones exist too.